# bound of derivative of an analytic function whose real part is bounded on a disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic on $|z-z_0|\leq r$. If $|Re(f(z))|\leq M$, show that $|f'(z_0)|\leq \frac{2M}{r}.$

The condition on real part of $f$ is strange. I have tried to modify the proof of Borel-Caratheodory theorem, but it seems this only works when $f(z_0)=0$.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity let us assume that $z_0 = 0$ and $M=r=1$, so $f$ is analytic in the unit disk with $|\operatorname{Re}(f(z))|\leq 1$, and we want to show that $|f'(0)| \le 2$.

The assumptions on $f$ and the desired conclusion do not change if $f$ is replaced by $f-iy$ for some real number $y$, or if $f$ is replaced by $-f$. So without loss of generality we can assume that $f(0)$ is real and non-negative.

The function
$$
 g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{f(z)-2}
$$
is holomorphic in the unit disk with $|g(z)| < 1$, so that the  [Schwarz–Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick_theorem) can be applied to $g$ at $z=0$:
$$
 1 - |g(0)|^2 \ge |g'(0)| = \frac{2 |f'(0)|}{|f(0)-2|^2}  \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
|f'(0)| \le \frac{|f(0)-2|^2}{2} \le  2
$$
since $f(0)$ is a real number between $0$ and $1$. This concludes the proof.

The sharp bound is $|f'(0)| \le 4/\pi$, see for example [Estimate $|f’(0)|$ by $Re(f(z))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3581789/estimate-f-0-by-refz/3582719#3582719).

Comment: Thank you very much! The link you provided is also very helpful.